# IDE-Style program running

Tags: java

### My Goal

---

I am attempting to make a Java program in which a user can select any `.class` or `.jar` file from their computer. My program will then pop up a `JInternalFrame` with a `JEditorPane` in it as the console, capturing any console output from the user's program. When the user's program closes (calls `System.exit(int status);`), my program must not close along with it. My program might also have such features as a button to immediately stop the user's program and others an IDE would. My program need not compile Java code, only run `.class` and `.jar` files.

### My Experience

---

I have made a small test version of this program wherein I got two specific files from a package and had the user click one of two buttons, each representing one of the two programs. A press of a button calls the following method:

```
  private void run(Class runnable)
  {
    java.lang.reflect.Method[] m = runnable.getMethods();
    boolean hasMain = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
    {
      if (m[i].getName().equals("main") && m[i].getParameterTypes()[0].isArray() && m[i].getParameterTypes()[0].getName().contains("java.lang.String"))
        try
        {
          Object invoke = m[i].invoke(null, (Object)globalArgs);
          hasMain = true;
          hub.setExtendedState(Hub.ICONIFIED);
          numPrograms++;
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
          java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Hub.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, t);
          javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not run " + runnable.getName(), "Error in invocation", javax.swing.JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        finally
        {
          break;
        }
    }
    if (!hasMain)
      javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, runnable.getName()
                                                      + " does not have a public static main method that\nreturns void and takes in an array of Strings",
                                                "No main method", javax.swing.JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
```

This method successfully calls either program's main method and runs a copy of said program. However, when any of the programs this hub has started calls the `System.exit(int status)` command, the hub closes, too. Also, I haven't the slightest clue as to how to  capture console output.

### My Questions

---

Does anyone have any experience or advice they would be willing to share to help me make a fully-functional program that can...

1. Open and run a compiled Java file (remember that `.jar` files may have more than one class with `main(String[] args)` method)
2. <s>Catch `System.exit(int status);` so that the hub program handles the internal program's exiting</s>
3. Catch `new java.io.PrintStream().println(Object o)` and similar calls and place their output in a `JEditorPane`
4. Make a button that, when pressed, stops the internal program from running
5. Possibly make all `JFrame`s the internal program uses into `JInternalFrame`s and place them in a `JDesktopPane`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want the other program (which you call through it's main method) to be able to shut down the JVM you're running in, you have, as I see it, three options:

### 1. Using a SecurityManager

Set up the **SecurityManager** so that it prevents the `System.exit` call:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkExit(int status) {
                throw new SecurityException("Client program exited.");
            }
        });

        try {
            System.out.println("hello");
            System.exit(0);
            System.out.println("world");
        } catch (SecurityException se) {
            System.out.println(se.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Prints**:

```
hello
Client program exited.
```

This is probably the nicest solution. This is the way application servers prevent an arbitrary servlet from terminating the entire server.

### 2. Separate JVM

Run the other program in a separate JVM, using for instance `ProcessBuilder`

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "other.Program");
        pb.redirectErrorStream();
        Process p = pb.start();
        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        int ch;
        while ((ch = is.read()) != -1)
            System.out.print((char) ch);
        is.close();
        System.out.println("Client program done.");
    }
}
```

### 3. Use shutdown hooks instead

Don't disallow the termination of the JVM, but instead add shutdown-hooks that cleans up the "hub" and exits gracefully. (This option probably only makes sense if your running one "external" program at a time.)

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            public void run() { 
                System.out.println("Uninitializing hub...");
                System.out.println("Exiting gracefully.");
            }
        });

        // Run client program
        System.out.println("Running... running... running...");
        System.exit(0);

     }
}
```

**Prints:**

```
Running... running... running...
Uninitializing hub...
Exiting gracefully.
```

Comment: SecurityManager is most likely the best bet.

Comment: I like the first option, but how will the hub program exit, then?

Comment: I have listed all my questions if you care to look at them, again

Comment: just saying: I won't accept your answer because it only answers one of my questions.

Comment: I really think you should post one question per question. I don't think anyone will have the energy to answer all of your questions in one post. I have ideas for solutions on question 3 and 4, but I see no point in spending time with it since I don't have answers on all your questions.

Comment: For the sake of helping, please post your answers. I'll probably accept this answer if it answers enough questions. And again, how would I exit the hub if I implement the first one?

Comment: Another reason for splitting 5 question up into 5 stackoverflow-questions is that it get more accessible to other people coming from for instance google.

Comment: This one and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050036/how-do-i-open-and-run-a-compiled-java-file (more to come)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054860/make-a-button-that-when-pressed-stops-an-internal-program-from-running

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055303/how-do-i-catch-a-java-io-printstream-place-its-output-in-a-jeditorpane

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055467/is-it-possible-make-all-jframes-the-internal-program-uses-into-jinternalframes-an

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055652/how-do-i-make-a-java-io-file-into-a-java-lang-class-to-run-it