# How do I make a button that, when pressed, stops an internal program from running?

Tags: java

(individual question from [IDE-Style program running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002976/ide-style-program-running) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is probably to fork off a new JVM through `ProcessBuilder`.

It is however possible to kill the internal program (and all the threads it spawned) using ThreadGroups. (I don't recommend it though. It uses the `stop` method which according to docs is "***Deprecated***. This method is inherently unsafe. See Thread.stop() for details."):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        ThreadGroup internalTG = new ThreadGroup("internal");
        Thread otherProcess = new Thread(internalTG, "Internal Program") {
            public void run() {
                OtherProgram.main(new String[0]);
            }
        };

        System.out.println("Starting internal program...");
        otherProcess.start();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Killing internal program...");

        internalTG.stop();
    }
}
```

```
class OtherProgram {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Starting...");
                    try {
                        sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Stopping...");
                }
            }.start();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Starting internal program...
Starting...
Starting...
Starting...
Starting...
Starting...
Killing internal program...
```

Comment: I dislike this answer. You, as a programmer, should know that all good IDEs have a buttton that does what I want this one to do, so it must be possible.

Comment: Oh, wow... well, that's quite the edit, there. Nevermind that last comment. Why don't you recommend this?

Comment: I changed my answer a bit... still though, this is most likely *not* how good IDEs solve it ;)

Comment: No. Eclipse has it's own compiler... that sort of indicates how complicated their solution could be...

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the code in a separate JVM.  Use debugger interfaces to control that JVM.
2. Instrument the byte code of the classes you intend to run.  Insert cancellation checks at appropriate places, as well as trapping access to global JVM resources.

The second choice is probably an endless source of annoying bugs.