# How do I catch a java.io.PrintStream place its output in a JEditorPane?

Tags: java, jeditorpane, printstream

I am attempting to make a Java program in which a user can select any `.class` or `.jar` file from their computer. My program will then pop up a `JInternalFrame` with a `JEditorPane` in it as the console, capturing any console output from the user's program. Note that I do not want to capture just System.err or System.out calls, but ALL PrintStream calls that go to the console.

(individual question from [IDE-Style program running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002976/ide-style-program-running) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch everything that is printed through `System.out` using [`System.setOut`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29) like this:

```
import java.io.*;

class SystemOutLogging {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
                                                  ClassNotFoundException {
        final PrintStream original = System.out;

        System.setOut(new PrintStream("programlog.txt") {
            public void println(String str) {
                process(str + "\n");
            }

            public void print(String str) {
                process(str);
            }

            private void process(String str) {
                // Fill some JEditorPane
                original.println("Program printed: \"" + str + "\"");
            }
        });

        System.out.print("Hello ");
        System.out.println(" World");
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Program printed: "Hello "
Program printed: " World
"
```

(There is a [`System.setErr`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr%28java.io.PrintStream%29) and [`System.setIn`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn%28java.io.InputStream%29) that works similarly.)

If you want to catch stuff that the "subprogram" prints through `System.out.println` you're in trouble, because `System.out` is a static so if you launch multiple "subprograms" you'll end up with a mess (since you can't hand a separate `System` class to each subprogram).

In a situation like this, I honestly think it would be a better idea to launch a separate process through ProcessBuilder. The standard input / output streams of the resulting process could easily be logged.

(p.s. When I think about it, you could probably check the current thread group in the `println` implementation, and from that decide which subprogram that actually invoked the `println` method)

Comment: IDEs like NetBeans seem to have no trouble  capturing multiple programs' System.out calls.  Also, this does not address the part about placing all the calls in a JEditorPane

Comment: NetBeans and Eclipse are extremely complex pieces of software. Don't expect to be able to replicate their systems. The example I provided gives you a "process"-method. You do whatever you need with the strings in that method. Appending it to a JEditorPane shouldn't be too hard from that point.

Comment: while it's true that a single programmer should baulk before attempting something the size of Eclipse or NetBeans, they're still just programs. Replicating a bit of their functionality (in this case capturing process output) is not necessarily hard or something outside reasonable expectations.

Comment: @Burleigh Bear, agreed. In this case however, he doesn't want to spawn a new process. I for one can't see how to solve this elegantly...

Comment: ah, I didn't read his other question. Silly me. By the way, I like your p.s. in the answer. +1.

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting the user's .jar file using Runtime.exec(), you'll get a Process object. That Object will allow you access to the launched processes System.out, System.in and System.err streams.

See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

You can take read from the err and out streams, and append to your JEditorPane using the usual setText type methods.

Comment: If you read the related question, you'd know that he doesn't consider this as an option.