# Is it possible make all JFrames the internal program uses into JInternalFrames and place them in a JDesktopPane?

Tags: java, window, jframe, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

The goal is to have the user select a java program, then my program opens up a `JInternalFrame`  with a `JEditorPane` inside it as the console and places said `JInternalFrame` in a `JDeskopPane`. Is it possible to change all the `Window`s the user's program may open into `JInternalFrame`s and place them in said `JDesktopPane`, as well?

(individual question from [IDE-Style program running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002976/ide-style-program-running))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite sure that this would not be possible to do without tampering with the binaries of the program that you're launching. If the target program performs something like `new Window().show()`, you'll have little possibilities to "hook into" the system, and tell it to swap it for a `JInternalFrame`.

What I'm saying is that if the program is written and compiled to show a top-level window, there is little you could do to change that. There is no "hook" into the system, with which you can say "put all future `Window`s into this `JInternalFrame`.

Comment: I ended up making it an API-style thing, where if people wanna use my system, they have to use my custom windows.