# How do I make a java.io.File into a java.lang.Class to run it?

Tags: java, class, file, jar

I have a program that lets a user select any `.class` or `.jar` file and run it. The problem is that, to run it, I need to use something other than a `java.io.File`, which is what a `JFileChooser` returns. How can I make a `java.io.File` into a `java.lang.Class` or `java.util.jar.JarFile`?

Comment: Well, obtaining a JarFile from a File is simple.  There's a constructor for JarFile to do that.

Comment: @Mark: That's not what he wants, he want's to load it into the ClassLoader

Comment: @Tim: I know that's not what he wants, but it's what he asked for.  Loading it into the ClassLoader is easy, but starting the class without having the user specify the name is where it gets difficult.  I might supply an answer later.

Comment: As tim said.  Create a classloader, load the file into a byte array and bobs your uncle.  Of course what you run is a different kettle of fish, you could use rflection to get hold of a method and call it.  You sure you don't just want to spawn off a new jvm to start another java app?

Comment: @vickirk: Still missing the point that this is driven from knowing the class name.

Comment: It seems funny that the comments are used to stage possible fixes. I understand though, who wants to be downvoted for trying to help someone :)

Comment: @Mark: sorry, my last comment got you and tim mixed up.  Reread my comment with than in mind and only time i mention name is for method name, not class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `File` object of the class you want to load, you can use a `URLClassLoader` to load the class. The `File` object can provide the `URL`.

Comment: I implemented this way: "URLClassLoader ucl = new java.net.URLClassLoader(new java.net.URL[]{files[i].toURI().toURL()});". Now what?

Comment: @Supuhstar, now you use `ucl` to get a `Class` object via `ucl.loadClass(classname)` and use the class loaded to call a static method or create an object instance. NB, the classname must include the package, as in "java.lang.String".

Comment: how do i get the class' package info if all I have is the java.io.File of a .class file? I tried "Class<?> thisClass = ucl.loadClass(files[i].getPath());", but got a "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: J:\Java\Checkers\Checkers.class"

Comment: @Supuhstar, if your `File` is something like "C:\myProject\com\example\Myclass.class" you must split it into parts "C:\myProject" for the clas path, "com.example" for the package and "Myclass" for the classname. If the user of your application selects the class file and its classpath folder, you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: That's just it. I DON'T know what the file is gonig to be. The user chooses it.

Comment: @Supuhstar, so let the user chose both the class file, **and** the classpath folder, then your application can use the 2 points to split the file path in 3 giving all the info you need.

Comment: How can I make that user-friendly for people who don't know what a classpath is (AKA the average person)

Comment: @Supuhstar, you might introduce the notion of "project", let the user chose that first and present classes found below that point to choose from. At some point your user must know something about Java classes or what is the point of running the class for them?

Comment: the point is that I am going to make a "virtual desktop" for Java programs. It looks like and feels like an operating system, but runs Java programs only

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need infer the classpath from a class itself. This isn't the easiest thing to do.

Your best bet is to parse the file using a tool such as asm.objectweb.org, and find the package of the class and infer the classpath root from the combination of the class's package and the filename. Even then, you are assuming that this class only uses classes in this one files directory.